# "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop." when using React Dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false)

return (<>
    <div className='mx-2' onClick={() => setDropdownOpen(!dropdownOpen)}>
        {user?.name}
    </div>
    <NavDropdown id="basic-nav-dropdown">
        <NavDropdown.Item>
            Logout
        </NavDropdown.Item> 
        <NavDropdown.Item href="/profile">
            Profile
        </NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Divider />
        <NavDropdown.Item href="/cart">
            Shopping Cart
        </NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="/order">
            Order
        </NavDropdown.Item>
    </NavDropdown>
</>)
```

I am trying to use different methods by clicking on the `{user?.name}` to open the dropdown menu, but an error occurred:

> Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

How do I achieve the clicking effect on the name, and enable the dropdown to appear accordingly?

Comment: please add more code of you component, how you are using the state in it.
and make sure you are not calling any setState method without arrow function or in useEffect without dependency array.

Comment: The code about which component you mean?

Comment: full code of this component that you have shared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add one prop `show` in `NavDropdown`.
The `show` prop is used to conditionally render the `NavDropdown` based on the state of `dropdownOpen`

```
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);


  return (
    <>
      <div className='mx-2' onClick={() => setDropdownOpen(!dropdownOpen)}>
        {user?.name}
      </div>

      <NavDropdown show={dropdownOpen} id="basic-nav-dropdown"> // set show={dropdownOpen}
        <NavDropdown.Item>
          Logout
        </NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="/profile">
          Profile
        </NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Divider />
        <NavDropdown.Item href="/cart">
          Shopping Cart
        </NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="/order">
          Order
        </NavDropdown.Item>
      </NavDropdown>
    </>
  );
```